# Writing a formula below a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix environment:

```
\begin{bmatrix}

 ...

\end{bmatrix}
```

How can I write below that matrix?
I tried with `substack`, so I wrote `\end{bmatrix}_{\substack{...}}`

That doesn't work as it does with, for example, a sum.
How can I write a formula exactly below the matrix?

EDIT: Okay, I found out how to do it myself now by using the array environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsopn,amscd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c}
A : =
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
a
\end{bmatrix} \\
x=0
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts from `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates your problem.

Comment: This surely works: `\begin{matrix}\begin{bmatrix}<matrix>\end{bmatrix}\\<formula>\end{matrix}` but some of the context in which you want this would help.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are already using `amsmath`, it's better to use its environments:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
A : =
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
a
\end{bmatrix} \\
x=0
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}
```

In this case the difference is not evident, but `array` adds spaces at both sides that `matrix` doesn't.

[image]

If you want that the condition is exactly below the matrix and not centered also with respect to `A:=`, then an `array` is the way to go, but in a more sophisticated fashion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % load also amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
A : = {} &
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
a
\end{bmatrix} \\
& \mathclap{x=0}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An equation below the matrix in normal size looks a little odd, if the equation is just an annotation/index to the matrix. The following uses the same method as putting equations below `\sum`, `\prod` and other operators:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsopn,amscd}
\usepackage{colonequals}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A \colonequals
\mathop{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x \\
  y \\
  z \\
  a
  \end{bmatrix}
}\limits_{x=0}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is what I would consider the good approach, it was exactly my thought when I read the question!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `\underset`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsopn,amscd}

\begin{document}

$A:=\underset{
\begin{array}{c}
x=0
\end{array}
}{
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\ 
a
\end{bmatrix}
}$



\end{document}
```

to create

[image]

ADDED. Comparison between the above code and as commented by egreg:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsopn,amscd}
\begin{document}
Original

$A:=\underset{
\begin{array}{c}
x=0
\end{array}
}{
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\ 
a
\end{bmatrix}
}$

As per egreg's comment

$A:=\underset{
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
x=0
\end{array}
}{
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ 
y \\ 
z \\ 
a
\end{bmatrix}
}$
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: The `array` may be useful if there are more then one conditions. However I'd use `\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}` to remove the extra space at both sides.

Comment: I would maybe consider `\mathclap{x=0}` since its far away from the rest of the equation so it doesn't need to occupy any horizontal space

Comment: @tohecz I wouldn't use such a build up anyway, since probably a subscript to the main matrix would be less ambiguous. Whether using `\mathclap` depends mostly on what similar conditions are used throughout the document.

Comment: @tohecz I am not familiar with `\mathclap`. I've tried to insert it but an error appeared.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Sorry, it needs `\usepackage{mathtools}`, and then you put `\mathclap{x=0}` instead of simple `x=0`, it makes `x=0` occupy no horizontal space, which seems to be good here.

Comment: @tohecz Thanks. Now I've managed to make it work as indicated by you.